# Can I back up my DevOps organization outside of Microsoft Azure servers?

Tags: azure-devops, backup

At the moment I have an organization in DevOps with several associated projects, the idea is to be able to protect my data due to internal backup policies, I understand that Microsoft has data redundancy between its datacenters but I want to make external backups and how they would be restored in case of a catastrophe.

Any feedback would be helpful, thank you very much. Additionally, I'm using Azure DevOps Services.

Comment: Do you want a backup of your code repositories or a backup of your work items?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlike Azure DevOps Server/TFS, there is no built-in method to backup the data of organization on Azure DevOps Services. And there seems is no method/tool to backup the whole organization data at once.

You can try to search whether there are any 3rd-party tools that can backup each individual service (**`Azure Repos`**, **`Azure Boards`**, **`Azure Pipelines`**, **`Azure Test Plans`** and **`Azure Artifacts`**) from Azure DevOps Services organization. You can try to search for some keywords like as "**`Backup Azure DevOps organization data`**" using Microsoft Bing or Google to look for the possible 3rd-party backup tools.

Generally, the 3rd-party backup tools are not free, and you may need to pay for some licenses on the tools.